# Saving / dumping network configuration with gateway and dns?

Tags: networking, netsh

Using the command `netsh interface dump > dumpfile.cfg` I get my network configuration in a script format that can be reloaded by `netsh exec dumpfile.cfg`. In the retrieved file there is no mention of gateway and dns address... why? Any alternative way to really save and restore the actual network configuration?

Contents of my dumpfile:

```
#========================
# Interface configuration
#========================
pushd interface 


popd
# End of interface configuration



# ----------------------------------
# IPHTTPS Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface httpstunnel

reset


popd
# End of IPHTTPS configuration



# ----------------------------------
# IPv4 Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface ipv4

reset
set global icmpredirects=enabled
add route prefix=0.0.0.0/0 interface="Local Area Connection" nexthop=169.254.144.200 metric=1 publish=Yes
add address name="VirtualBox Host-Only Network" address=192.168.56.1 mask=255.255.255.0
add address name="VMware Network Adapter VMnet1" address=192.168.6.1 mask=255.255.255.0
add address name="VMware Network Adapter VMnet8" address=192.168.111.1 mask=255.255.255.0
add address name="Local Area Connection" address=169.254.144.155 mask=255.255.255.0


popd
# End of IPv4 configuration



# ----------------------------------
# IPv6 Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface ipv6

reset
set interface interface="Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface" forwarding=disabled advertise=disabled mtu=1280 metric=0 siteprefixlength=0 nud=disabled routerdiscovery=disabled managedaddress=disabled otherstateful=disabled weakhostsend=disabled weakhostreceive=disabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled advertisedrouterlifetime=0 advertisedefaultroute=disabled currenthoplimit=0 forcearpndwolpattern=disabled enabledirectedmacwolpattern=disabled


popd
# End of IPv6 configuration



# ----------------------------------
# ISATAP Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface isatap



popd
# End of ISATAP configuration



# ----------------------------------
# 6to4 Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface 6to4

reset



popd
# End of 6to4 configuration



# ----------------------------------
# ISATAP Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface isatap



popd
# End of ISATAP configuration


#========================
# Port Proxy configuration
#========================
pushd interface portproxy

reset


popd

# End of Port Proxy configuration



# ----------------------------------
# TCP Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface tcp

reset

set global rss=enabled chimney=automatic autotuninglevel=normal congestionprovider=none ecncapability=disabled timestamps=disabled netdma=enabled dca=enabled

Dump has failed when retreiving chimneyapplication  settings.

Dump has failed when retreiving chimneyapplication  settings.

Dump has failed when retreiving chimneyapplication  settings.

Dump has failed when retreiving chimneyapplication  settings.


popd
# End of TCP configuration



# ----------------------------------
# Teredo Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface teredo
set state type=client servername=teredo.ipv6.microsoft.com. servervirtualip=0.0.0.0



popd
# End of Teredo configuration



# ----------------------------------
# 6to4 Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface 6to4

reset



popd
# End of 6to4 configuration
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found at the [microsoft forum a thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a15f2b3a-da4a-4675-92b2-c16b726203ca/netsh-dump-are-incorrect-and-incomplete-?forum=winserverNIS) that says to use an addtional -c parameter:

```
netsh –c interface dump
```

Only that this does not write out the gateway as "gateway" but as "nexthop" and I don't see the DNS entry in there... this is not a workable solution for anything as I see, but this is the most I could get out of netsh with dump/restore.